# Enter a valid URI error in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, node-red, azure-logic-apps

I am currently trying out Azure Logic Apps and am now trying to create 
a first simple flow that acquires data from an external REST API.

I'm using FRED, a hosted Node-Red instance, to create an REST API end-point.
In FRED you use https://x_y.fred.sensetecnic.com/api/hello to access my mock API (where x_y is my user name).

Accessing "https://x_y.fred.sensetecnic.com/api/hello" in a browser returns the intended data as specified in the Node-Red flow. Same thing goes when accessing
"https://x_y.fred.sensetecnic.com/api/hello" using GET in Postman (then adding two required Headers, required by FRED).

The strange thing is that in my Azure Logic App, I am not able to even save the flow with my URI stated as "https://x_y.fred.sensetecnic.com/api/hello". It states "Enter a valid URI". I enter the headers as was required.

So I can get to the REST API directly from a browser or using Postman, but are not able to access it from within an Azure Logic App.

Answer (score 3):

I test the problem is there is a special characters `_` in your URI. You could have a try if you delete `_` then it won't state error.

So you coudl Initialize a variable to store your name `x_y`, then insert the variable in the URI. The flow would be like this. If you don't find the `name` in Dynamic content, you could use `variables('name')` this expression to insert it.

[image]

With this way the GET method will run correctly.

[image]

Comment: @Tobias Persson,did you don't know how to mark the answer? On the left of my reply, there is an option to mark.